# spring integration JMS message driven channel adaptor using selector

Tags: java, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

`<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`

Using message driven adapter , i want to filter message from AMQ broker using selector .

message has to filtered against dynamic bean variable value which is validated using selector bean ref option

Comment: Your question is not clear; the selector cannot be changed at runtime (without stopping/starting the container); it is baked into the consumer during initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,    I want to filter message using selector attribute in Message driven channel adaptor . i was able to call bean method inside selector attribute @bean.method() , but not able to pass header parameter to that method @bean.method(header.param) . I am expecting selector should validate dynamically passing the header parameter to bean method and return boolean result so that message can be filtered.

Comment: <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    connection-factory="connectionFactoryName"
    destination="destinationName" channel="channelName" 
    selector="#{@bean.method(header.param)}"
    auto-startup="false"/>   the above selector attribute has bean method configured to receive header param dynamically whenever pick message from AMQ . but it is syntactically wrong not able to pass header param. can you help

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in comments; it's hard to read; edit the question instead. See my answer, you don't seem to understand what a message selector is.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to your comments..

> Thanks for your reply , I want to filter message using selector attribute in Message driven channel adaptor . i was able to call bean method inside selector attribute @bean.method() , but not able to pass header parameter to that method @bean.method(header.param) . I am expecting selector should validate dynamically passing the header parameter to bean method and return boolean result so that message can be filtered.

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter connection-factory="connectionFactoryName" 
     destination="destinationName" channel="channelName" 
     selector="#{@bean.method(header.param)}" auto-startup="false"/>
```

> the above selector attribute has bean method configured to receive header param dynamically whenever pick message from AMQ . but it is syntactically wrong not able to pass header param. can you help?

You don't seem to understand what a JMS message selector is...

```
selector="foo='bar'"
```

...tells the broker to only send messages with the `foo` property equal to `bar`.
It is configured on the consumer during startup.

What you have is not "dynamic". `#{...}` expressions are evaluated once during context initialization.

What you are trying to do makes no sense; there is no "message" from which to evaluate a header yet. You can't tell the broker which message(s) to send, based on the contents of a message. The filtering is done on the broker before sending the message(s).

If you don't mind "losing" the messages you are not interested in (or are consuming from a topic) and you want to filter the messages you want to process, then add a

```
<filter ... expression="#{@bean.method(header.param)}" />
```

after the adapter. You could use the discard channel to republish the ignored message(s) to another queue (or do something else with them).